# BottomNavigationBarXF design issue

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i created a blank forms app and implemented the library BottomNavigationBarXF with nuget.
but the design is not working or maybe a part, i see it like a normal toolbar:

https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3ckpYOVVyMFpJSzg/components_tabs_usage_desktop7.png

After the installation of the library i implement this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
xmlns:example="clr-namespace:BottomBarXFExampleXaml;assembly=BottomBarXFExampleXaml"
             x:Class="BottomBarXFExampleXaml.BarPage">

<example:TabPage Title="Favorites" Icon="ic_favorites.png" />
<example:TabPage Title="Friends" Icon="ic_friends.png" />
<example:TabPage Title="Nearby" Icon="ic_nearby.png"  />
<example:TabPage Title="Recents" Icon="ic_recents.png"  />
<example:TabPage Title="Restaurants" Icon="ic_restaurants.png"/>
</xf:BottomBarPage>

public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new BarPage();
    }
```

Must i implement something else, maybe a design file or should all be in the library?

Thanks

Comment: You should put the code in the question not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The library was only implemented to the forms project not to the droid project.